# Who planned or ordered to kill Bran?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In Martin's **A Game of Thrones** Bran is attacked by a person by a Valyrian blade but fails and gets killed by Bran's direwolf. But in this or any other novel of this series it is never cleared who planned the murder. Who actually ordered to kill Bran? Have I missed anything so that I don't know?